# Google Analytics Event not firing containing hit type

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've got a small little internal app that counts code, and I'm trying to set it up so that Google Analytics logs an event everytime somebody uses it, but the problem is, the event isn't logging. I've got my google analytics tag in my head, but when I call the following function:

```
ga("send", "event", "code", "counted", "Counted Code", jsonReturn.data.raw_total);
```

Once my ajax call to actually count the code has completed, nothing happens. There is no event logged in Google Analytics.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**--------------------- EDIT ---------------------**

Here is the surrounding code where it is called:

```
window.addEventListener("repofound", (ev:CustomEvent) => {

    const repoUrl:string = ev.detail;
    const ajax:XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", "https://URLtoServer" + repoUrl);
    ajax.send();
    ajax.onload = () => {

        countButton.removeAttribute("aria-busy");

        const jsonReturn = JSON.parse(ajax.response);

        if (jsonReturn.success) {

            ga("send", "event", "code", "counted", "Counted Code", jsonReturn.data.raw_total);

            // specific client side UI code that is most definitely firing

        }

    };


}, false);
```

Comment: Can you add the code that surrounds your GA call (above)?

Comment: @EdLucas edited to add the surrounding code

Comment: is there any console messages?

Comment: do you have `analytics.js tag` in the head or `gtag` snippet?

Comment: No console error messages, and yes, here is my tag:<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=MINE"></script>
 <script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());

   gtag('config', 'MINE');
 </script>

Comment: Could you check out network tab. If there are a request to google analytics after ajax request it means the request received by google but is not processed (maybe due invalid data). If there are not a request to google that means the issue is in client side.

Comment: @MisirJafarov there is nothing being logged in the network tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment it is clear that you are using the `gtag` library while the event is sending it with `ga` (Analytics Universal).

So you need to edit your event from this:

```
ga("send", "event", "code", "counted", "Counted Code", jsonReturn.data.raw_total);
```

To this:

```
gtag('event', 'counted', {
  'event_category': 'code',
  'event_label': 'Counted Code',
  'value': jsonReturn.data.raw_total
});
```